# Unhandled rejection Error: insufficient funds BitGo js

Tags: node.js

I am using the BitGo js **Send Transaction(wallet Operation)** to send the btc.When i passing dynamic values. Following is my bitGo js code:

```
// passing these values dynamically
let params ={  
    amount : jsondata.amt * 1e8,
    address: jsondata.raddress,
    walletPassphrase: jsondata.passphrase
};     
wallet.send(params)
.then(function(transaction) {
  // print transaction details
  console.dir(transaction);
});
```

**It through an error : Unhandled rejection Error: insufficient funds**
 I have sufficient balance to send btc. but not work for dynamic values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bitgo uses a transaction fee every time you make a transaction. When you are doing it dynamically, it will be using another address in your wallet for the transaction fee. Please make sure you have sent sufficient funds to that address. Generally you need to send funds to that address, so that Bitgo can use it for transaction fee. Let me know if it helps.

Comment: ok, means due to additional transaction fees, i was unable to send btc.Thank you, it help me lot